# Android privileges to execute native applications?

Tags: android, linux, permissions, native

I downloaded the c4droid app for Android and am running commands through `system();`.  I'm learning that somethings work while others don't.  Most of the cool stuff don't work and this appears to be due to my user profile not being given the rights to execute such commands at the Linux OS level.

So tried another experiment.  I got a special Gnu compiler for the arm processor and compiled a simple hello world app.  Then I put on my phone and tried to execute it through the c4droid app like `system("./myapp.bin");` .  I got a `permission denied` message.

So I'm just trying to understand what I can do and what I can't do on my phone that paid good money for?  Can I execute such a hello world app or not?  Do I really need root access to execute an application I made?  Is there a way to get my code to run by wrapping it in android/java code?  Do I have to go through the Dalvikvm to get this to run?

I'm really looking for a way to do this without rooting it or downloading something like busybox and using su.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many many different issues.

1. `permission denied` is one of the few error messages the primitive shell knows, and it's used for many other types of failures including not finding the requested command.
2. The toolbox suite is missing many typical unix commands.   People sometimes install busybox as a more comprehensive supplement
3. Some of the things you may want to do will actually require permissions that the `shell` (or even more so, application user id) accounts do not have.  Only on an emulator or engineering device does the adb shell run as root by default, though on a 'rooted' device you may be able to get to a root shell.
4. You do not need root access to run compiled code, however the code must have a suitable ABI, must have all it's library dependencies satisfied, and must be installed in a file with the executable flag, on a partition which is not mounted with non-executable flag.  Some of the issues you face there are glibc (or other) vs Android's bionic libc.  Executable scratch directories vary by android version, though the private storage area of an app is an option if the app sets the file to world readable and executable.
5. The usual (and only "recommended") means of running native code is to build it as a shared library linked against android's Bionic libc, and call into it from a dalvik/java app using JNI.

Comment: yes I know.  But I'd think `./myapp.bin` would get it to run barring any technical issues.

Comment: That typically faces three issues - execute flag on the file, no execute flag on the partition, and libc (in)compatibility.

Comment: How about running the executable through a standard android application?

Comment: Any invocation of exec() will face the same issues, the only difference being which user's permissions apply.  The standard mechanism is jni shared libraries - the executable flag issue still applies, but the android installation system will set it for you on legitimate and properly packaged libraries.

Comment: You basically answered all my questions.  I'm marking this as the answer.